# Stochastic Calculus Algebra

Tags: brownian-motion, stochastic-calculus

Studying Brownian Motion and stochastic integrals in class, my professor rewrote this summand $$1/2*\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} (W((j+1)T/n) - W(jT/n))^2$$ as $$1/2*W^2(T) + \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} W(jT/n)(W(jT/n) - W((j+1)T/n))$$

I can't figure out the algebra between these two steps. I've been trying looking at it as a telescopic sum but can't seem to get the same expression. Did my professor make a mistake or am I missing something?

Comment: Try expanding the square and rearranging terms. Consider the summand and attempt the equality via induction.